# PowerShell script to download images by item field value

Tags: list, powershell, splistitem, image

I've [found this great script](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/varun_malhotra/archive/2012/02/08/sharepoint-2010-powershell-download-all-files-in-document-library-to-network-share-file-share.aspx) that downloads all images and their folders from a given library.

I'd like to update it so that it only gets images that have a certain value for the product code. However when I try to just log the code filed I'm getting a null value.

```
$destination = "D:\\images"
$webUrl = "https://site.local/"
$listUrl = "https://site.local/images"
##############################################################

$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity $webUrl
$list = $web.GetList($listUrl)
$spQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
$camlQuery = '<Query>
                <Where>
                    <and>
                        <Neq>
                            <FieldRef Name='Code' />
                            <Value Type='Lookup'>''</Value>
                        </Neq>
                        <Eq>
                            <FieldRef Name='Created' />
                            <Value Type='DateTime'><Today /></Value>
                        </Eq>
                    </and>
                </Where>
            </Query>'
$spQuery.Query = $camlQuery
$spListItems = $list.GetItems($spQuery)

function ProcessFolder {
    param($folderUrl)
    $folder = $web.GetFolder($folderUrl)
    foreach ($file in $folder.Files) {
        #Customising Varun Malhotra script
        #Get value of Product Code
        $item = $list.Items[0]
        Write-Host $item["Code"].ToString()

        Write-Host $item

        #Ensure destination directory
        $destinationfolder = $destination + "/" + $folder.Url 
        if (!(Test-Path -path $destinationfolder))
        {
            $dest = New-Item $destinationfolder -type directory 
        }

        Write-Host $file

        #Download file
        $binary = $file.OpenBinary()
        $stream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($destinationfolder + "/" + $file.Name), Create
        $writer = New-Object System.IO.BinaryWriter($stream)
        $writer.write($binary)
        $writer.Close()
        }
}

#Download root files
ProcessFolder($list.RootFolder.Url)
#Download files in folders
foreach ($folder in $list.Folders) {
    ProcessFolder($folder.Url)
}
```

I think I'm not getting the $item correctly as I've already got the list of files??

EDIT: I've updated the script with a Caml Query that will find only the items I want. I'm now not sure how I can get $spListItems to fit into the ProcessFolder function so it can run for ALL folders in the library but only find the Caml selected items?

Comment: can you be more specific, as you said "only gets images that have a certain value for the product code" What is that certain means here, any specific value, or set of values.. or any values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this different way of doing a [powershell query](http://www.thorntontechnical.com/tech/sharepoint/quick-tip-sharepoint-powershell-get-items-in-a-list-based-on-custom-columns-and-other-hints#.VlZ-vISZZ0c) and modified it to suit what I was trying to do above. I also realised that I don't need the folder structure when exporting so that really simplified things.

```
Write-Host “Getting images from Diageo campaign manager….”
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -erroraction SilentlyContinue

######################## Start Variables ########################
$destination = "D:\\images\"
$webUrl = "https://site.local/"
$listUrl = "https://site.local/images"
##############################################################

#create the list
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity $webUrl
$list = $web.GetList($listUrl)

# get items from the list based on query
$listItems = $list.Items | ?{$_["code"] -eq "1"}

#loop through each of the found items and download
try
{
    foreach($listItem in $listItems)
    {
        #Write-Host $listItem["Title"]
        Write-Host "Downloading: "$listItem.Url

        #Downloading file
        $binary = $web.GetFile($listItem.Url).OpenBinary()
        $stream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($destination + "/" + $listItem.Name), Create
        $writer = New-Object System.IO.BinaryWriter($stream)
        $writer.write($binary)
        $writer.Close()
    }
}

catch
{
    write-host $_.exception

}

finally
{
    if($web -ne $null)
    {
        $web.Dispose()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `foreach` loop you are always selecting the first item from your list (not even filtered). You need to change the following line:

```
$item = $list.Items[0]
```

to this:

```
$item = $file.Item
```

Comment: Hi Paul,Thanks for the reply, though I'm still getting an error: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At D:\scripts\downloadImagesTo.ps1:23 char:13
+             Write-Host $item["Code"].ToString()
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: That means that "Code" column for that item is empty and the code fails when trying to convert "null" to "string" or the item itself is null. When using $item["ColumnName"], make sure that "ColumnName" is an internal column name and not the title. Try debugging your code line by line and you'll find out what's the problem.